# Bruteforce aes-256 encrypted 7zip archive with rarcrack

Tags: archive, 7zip, rarcrack

Gi, guys. My problem is that I encrypted some files with 7zip (AES-256), but I forgot the password for the archive.

As I see it, the solutions are brute forcing it with john the ripper or RarCrack.
While Rarcrack is fairly easy to use, I remember a part of my password and I want to optimize the process.

Rarcrack allows you to specify the characters with which you are going to bruteforce the archive, but it does not allow you to set a starting word (as far as I know).

Let's say my password was test1234. Instead of trying with chars tes0123456789, I want to start the bruteforcing with the string "test" and then try with 0123456789.

Anyone knows a way of doing that?

Comment: Approximately how long was your password?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [7zrecover](http://rsm.imap.cc/software/gnu-linux/software/7zrecover), it is easy to use and if you know what words could be in your password you will get it back pretty fast.

7z encryption is a pain ass, it is specially made to slow brute force attacks.
Good luck!